# 70s novel with giant ants pretending to be aliens

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

Probably written in the late 1970s. Young adult.

- Two boys, the narrator and his friend, are abducted by a flying saucer.
- The aliens are roughly human-sized and the boys don't get a good look at them except that their skin is like a dark shell. I learned the word "chitin" from this.
- For some reason the kids get suspicious that things aren't what they seem, and maybe this isn't even a spaceship.
- In fact the "aliens" are from Earth, and they're **giant intelligent ants**. They evolved underground, and they're getting ready to come up and maybe take over.
- There's a scene where the kids are trying to talk with each other about this but they're worried that the ants can hear them, so they start talking about people with made-up names that are really acronyms, e.g. "Ann Nocenti and Ted Stearn" = ants [that is not a real example].

I don't remember what happens after that.